# Shell command to reverse each line of file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file *test.txt* with the following text

```
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
8 7 3 2
```

I want to save it as

```
4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3
2 3 7 8
```

Is there any shell command which does that?

Comment: Do you really want to reverse lines or invert the actual columns?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`rev` will do the job:

```
rev file
4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3
2 3 7 8
```